# How to give some margin between buttons? (database content)

Tags: html, css

I have this buttons in my website but the margin top and bottom doesn´t work, i think its because the content is dinamically from my database.. i have the same problem but with my gallery, someone knows how to fix it?
Basically i want to give some space between the buttons.
RESIZE WINDOW TO MOBILE TO SEE

[image]

```css
.divtitleCategoria{
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-category {
  color: var(--mainBlack) !important;
  border:1px #000 solid;
  margin:10px 8px;
  font-family:"Calibri";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:16px;
}
.btn-category:hover {
  color: var(--mainTinto) !important;
  background-color:#fff;
}
.inline{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
  <div id="get_category">
      <div class='divtitleCategoria'>
            <li  class='inline' > 
   <a href='#'  class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>herehereherehere</a>
   </li>
          <li  class='inline' > 
    <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>hereherehereherehere</a>
           </li>
           <li  class='inline' > 
   <a href='#'  class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>hereherehereherehere</a>
     </li>       
          <li  class='inline' > 
   <a href='#'  class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>hereherehereherehere</a>
    </li>       
                    
     
       </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Fix that first.

Comment: You can´t run the code snippet? Here it works...

Comment: "It works" is no excuse for invalid/error filled markup that will continue to give you issues ongoing and you'll be back here again asking more questions.

Comment: But why is invalid? Everything is well written...
Forget about the id="get_category". Thats the only thing that is not here, because it calls JS file and PHP..

Comment: As mentioned elsewhere, a `<div>` element cannot contain `<li>` elements. `<li>` elements must have a `<ul>` as a parent. Running your HTML through the validator, which every professional does, would have shown you this obvious mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to 100% replicate with the given code, but I believe you just need to add `display: inline-block;` to your `.btn-category` class.

Also you should have a `<ul>` tag surrounding your list items.

```css
.divtitleCategoria {
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-category {
  color: var(--mainBlack) !important;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  margin: 10px 8px;
  font-family: "Calibri";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.btn-category:hover {
  color: var(--mainTinto) !important;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
  <div id="get_category">
    <div class='divtitleCategoria'>
      <ul>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
        <li class='inline'>
          <a href='#' class=' inline btn btn-category text-uppercase'>aqui</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've edited the full button code. Watch now please.
I used inline because if i use inline-block , buttons will appear one per line..

Comment: I'd need to see your CSS for the `li` tag. Please reproduce the full issues in a stack snippet within your post.

Comment: Done! Resize your window to mobile to see.
I want go give some "margin top" but doesn´t work...

Comment: Still not seeing how inline-block doesn't fix this problem. Updated my answer to include your example.

Comment: The inline-block will give me one button per line, and i want to stay everything in one line and when I resize my browser the buttons have to go to other line but with some margin-top

Comment: If you run the code in my answer it is not one per line. So the problem is in part of the code that you haven't shared.

Comment: Yes, you are right, i tried but my Xampp was not updating the CSS .
Thanks!

Comment: @abney317 You made the same blundering error the OP did. You are using invalid HTML and made that "work". "It works" for now but it is now his Chernobyl and you helped melt the core.

Comment: A little over the top there @Rob .. added the `<ul>` correction as well

Comment: Calling the invalid HTML a blunder, no, it's not over the top. It's an amateur mistake.

Comment: It's his code. My original answer only had the CSS changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wrap the < li> tags under a < ul> parent tag.

Comment: With <ul> he makes one button per line, like "display:inline-block"

Comment: < ul> can be styled to display <li > items in a horizontal/ wrapped list using float or display inline block

Another thing could be to use the bootstrap grids -> col- classes

Answer (score 0):

You are apparently using Bootstrap so after removing all your CSS and just using basic bootstrap markup, buttons are evenly spaced.  But Buttons are inline elements, if they are not being laid out correctly it's due to your combination of html/css overriding default behaviors.

Also, keep in mind that the bootstrap `xs` grid classes (  `col-xs-*` ) keeps things horizontal at all times regardless of media size.

```css
.box {
  border: 10px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#ButtonsWithMoreMargin .btn {
  margin: 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Basic Buttons -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="box">
      <a href='#' class='btn btn-default text-uppercase'>herehereherehere</a>
      <a href='#' class='btn btn-default text-uppercase'>hereherehereherehere</a>
      <a href='#' class='btn btn-default text-uppercase'>hereherehereherehere</a>
      <a href='#' class='btn btn-default text-uppercase'>hereherehereherehere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Buttons With Margins -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    <div id="ButtonsWithMoreMargin" class="box">
      <a href='#' class='btn btn-default text-uppercase'>herehereherehere</a>
      <a href='#' class='btn btn-default text-uppercase'>hereherehereherehere</a>
      <a href='#' class='btn btn-default text-uppercase'>hereherehereherehere</a>
      <a href='#' class='btn btn-default text-uppercase'>hereherehereherehere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The isse was fixed but that works too, thanks for try to help!